# Excel's add-in: Cannot find Reference or Library

Tags: excel, vba, reference, add-in

After finishing an add-in I started testing it on other computers. There is this one computer that I get the following message:

Can't find project or library

Note: This computer is running Excel 2010 and I've tested it successfully only on Excel 2013 computers. They both have the same references as shown bellow:

[image]

Prompt me if any other information is necessary:

Answer (score 1):

MS Office 15 is the library of code that is delivered with office 2013.

As your code is using early binding (google it), you need a reference to a library that has the same code for your code to use when working with 2010.

Older version of excel came with an older library that has an older version of the same code (with some extra bits too).  You need to change the reference in the file when using the workbook on older version of excel OR change your code to use late binding.

It might be easier for you to simply change the reference and save the file as "Myfielname 2010version" and use this copy with excel 2010 and a different file with excel 2013.

Excel 2010 library will have the same name but with a different number (eg 13) and you will find it further down the list.

You can add code that detects the version, but you don't want to go there.

Answer (score 0):

First I've just realized the reference list is for each workbook/add-in and not for the system as a whole. There was a missing reference to the solver add-in on the other computer. VBE doesn't run the project with a missing reference. I will post how to automatically check and add it here when I find out How.